# Alternatives to browser based animations

Tags: animation

I have developed a scrolling guide for a television company but attempting to use CSS animations, jquery animate, and velocity.js have all failed me.  They work as intended but the animation is choppy and almost gives a pulse feel to it.  I considered attemping to go down the route of creating this canvas base but wondering if I am going down another path that will not work.  My last resort I figured would be making this flash based.

What other alternatives could I use for this?

http://announcements.video-direct.net/guide?uid=20&cp=1

Comment: Surely this is a better fit for [webapps.se]?

Comment: @Oded - no.  From their description: "Don't ask about [...] creating or developing a web application".

Comment: @Jules - this isn't about a whole application. It is specifically about an approach to animation on the web, but yes, if they don't talk development at all then I am completely in the wrong.

Comment: @Oded - but it is a question about developing a web application, albeit restricted to the narrow field of animation within that application.

Comment: @Jules - I was agreeing with you ;)

Comment: Is the linked-to page what you're working on?

Comment: THat is the link that I created.  I am looking for an alternative approach as my approach did not work as intended